# how do you re-organize data frame in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have this data frame:

```
            DATE    pc       SERVER
1  2013-02-16 01:00:00  3.83 server1
2  2013-02-16 02:00:00  3.45 server1
3  2013-02-16 03:00:00  3.34 server1
4  2013-02-16 04:00:00  3.73 server1
5  2013-02-16 05:00:00  3.16 server1
6  2013-02-16 06:00:00  3.16 server1
7  2013-02-16 01:00:00 4.74 server2
8  2013-02-16 02:00:00 5.70 server2
9  2013-02-16 03:00:00  8.54 server2
10 2013-02-16 04:00:00  9.25 server2
11 2013-02-16 05:00:00 10.12 server2
12 2013-02-16 06:00:00 10.15 server2
```

On the SERVER column there are 8 servers. I need to group each server by the DATE. For example,

this is what I need this df to look;

```
 DATE               server1   server2
 2013-02-16 01:00:00  3.83     4.74
 2013-02-16 02:00:00  3.45     5.50
 2013-02-16 03:00:00  3.34     8.54
 2013-02-16 04:00:00  3.73     9.25
```

etc

How would I do this, re-organize my data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very basic `reshape` problem. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="DATE", timevar="SERVER")
                 DATE pc.server1 pc.server2
1 2013-02-16 01:00:00       3.83       4.74
2 2013-02-16 02:00:00       3.45       5.70
3 2013-02-16 03:00:00       3.34       8.54
4 2013-02-16 04:00:00       3.73       9.25
5 2013-02-16 05:00:00       3.16      10.12
6 2013-02-16 06:00:00       3.16      10.15
```

Alternatively, using the "reshape2" package:

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(mydf, DATE ~ SERVER, value.var="pc")
                 DATE server1 server2
1 2013-02-16 01:00:00    3.83    4.74
2 2013-02-16 02:00:00    3.45    5.70
3 2013-02-16 03:00:00    3.34    8.54
4 2013-02-16 04:00:00    3.73    9.25
5 2013-02-16 05:00:00    3.16   10.12
6 2013-02-16 06:00:00    3.16   10.15
```

---

If you have duplicated combinations of "DATE" and "SERVER" then you need to add a secondary "ID" variable to your data.

Here's some sample data (please share your data in this form in the future):

```
mydf <- structure(list(DATE = c("2013-02-16 01:00:00", "2013-02-16 02:00:00", 
    "2013-02-16 03:00:00", "2013-02-16 04:00:00", "2013-02-16 05:00:00", 
    "2013-02-16 06:00:00", "2013-02-16 01:00:00", "2013-02-16 02:00:00", 
    "2013-02-16 03:00:00", "2013-02-16 04:00:00", "2013-02-16 05:00:00", 
    "2013-02-16 06:00:00", "2013-02-16 01:00:00"), pc = c(3.83, 3.45, 
    3.34, 3.73, 3.16, 3.16, 4.74, 5.7, 8.54, 9.25, 10.12, 10.15, 
    5.83), SERVER = c("server1", "server1", "server1", "server1", 
    "server1", "server1", "server2", "server2", "server2", "server2", 
    "server2", "server2", "server1")), .Names = c("DATE", "pc", "SERVER"
    ), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
    "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "data.frame")
mydf
#                   DATE    pc  SERVER
# 1  2013-02-16 01:00:00  3.83 server1
# 2  2013-02-16 02:00:00  3.45 server1
# 3  2013-02-16 03:00:00  3.34 server1
# 4  2013-02-16 04:00:00  3.73 server1
# 5  2013-02-16 05:00:00  3.16 server1
# 6  2013-02-16 06:00:00  3.16 server1
# 7  2013-02-16 01:00:00  4.74 server2
# 8  2013-02-16 02:00:00  5.70 server2
# 9  2013-02-16 03:00:00  8.54 server2
# 10 2013-02-16 04:00:00  9.25 server2
# 11 2013-02-16 05:00:00 10.12 server2
# 12 2013-02-16 06:00:00 10.15 server2
# 13 2013-02-16 01:00:00  5.83 server1
```

Notice that because of the duplicated "DATE" + "SERVER" combination in rows 1 and 13, we won't be able to use `reshape` without getting the warning you mentioned. The solution: *add a secondary ID*:

```
mydf$ID <- ave(as.character(mydf$DATE), mydf$DATE, mydf$SERVER, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar=c("DATE", "ID"), timevar="SERVER")
#                   DATE ID pc.server1 pc.server2
# 1  2013-02-16 01:00:00  1       3.83       4.74
# 2  2013-02-16 02:00:00  1       3.45       5.70
# 3  2013-02-16 03:00:00  1       3.34       8.54
# 4  2013-02-16 04:00:00  1       3.73       9.25
# 5  2013-02-16 05:00:00  1       3.16      10.12
# 6  2013-02-16 06:00:00  1       3.16      10.15
# 13 2013-02-16 01:00:00  2       5.83         NA
```

Comment: thank you. I get this error. Is this an ok error: Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for SERVER=server1: first taken

Comment: @user1471980, That's a warning, not an error. But no, I wouldn't consider it to be an OK warning. It probably means that you have duplicated combinations of your "DATE" and "SERVER" columns. Can you try `any(duplicated(mydf[c("DATE", "SERVER")]))` and see if that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @user1471980, then you need to add another "id" variable to make it work. Give me a few minutes to post an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `reshape` package, you could simply do. Consider the dataframe `df`:

```
 df = data.frame(DATE = c("2013-02-16", "2013-02-17", "2013-02-18", "2013-02-16", "2013-02-17", "2013-02-18"), SERVER = c("server1","server1","server1","server2","server2","server2"), pc = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

 cast(df, DATE ~ SERVER, value = 'pc', mean)
```

You get:

```
        DATE server1 server2
1 2013-02-16       1       4
2 2013-02-17       2       5
3 2013-02-18       3       6
```

Comment: where do you mention your data frame name. You just picked the column names?

Comment: You do know that the "reshape" package has pretty much been replaced by "reshape2", right?

Comment: @Mariam, this is not working. I get 0 and 1 in the new data frame. I need the values in my original df to spread out.

Comment: You must have some kind of bug on your end. It works perfectly for me. Just make sure that since you are using `pc` as the value column, it should be positioned last in your dataframe.

Comment: @Mariam, I doubt it's a bug at their end. It's more likely that you've provided somewhat incomplete code. In particular, you didn't specify the "value" column that `cast` should use. By default, `cast` looks for something named "value" or it uses the last column. In the OP's case, "pc" was not in the last position. Put "pc" as the second column and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Also, you haven't specified your "aggregation function", which in the case of multiple matches, will default to `length`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for the explanation! I have just started working with this package, and still don't know my way around very well! Thanks!

Comment: @Mariam, if you've just started with the package, then please consider jumping straight to "reshape2". It's generally faster and you at least know it's under development.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Sure, thanks! In the meantime, I have modified my answer. Please confirm whether this code is rather more complete than the previous one. Thanks.